# attempt to invoke directory as script?

Tags: apache

is something wrong with my apache config ?

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        AddHandler cgi-script pl cgi
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: read the title perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

nothing is wrong with your httpd configs, you need to configure httpd to redirect to the directory index. it is literally trying to execute the directory "/etc/www/cgi-bin" as cgi.